# Google PubSub message ordering for IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

We'd like to use the new [Message Ordering](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) feature for Google Cloud PubSub, but for [messages coming from IoT Devices hooked up to IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge).

The [documentation states](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#using_ordering_keys) that an `orderingKey` should be provided when publishing the messages. Examples are provided that are straightforward enough, but seem to apply to the [PubSub Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), whereas we are [publishing against the IoT Core API using MQTT](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge).

Is it possible to provide an ordering key through the IoT Core MQTT bridge, and if so, how should that be specified? I couldn't find any documentation or examples on the topic.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. IoT Core doesn't seem to be an hot topic for now. And this new PubSub features seem to have been forgotten. Same thing for the filtering.